# Counting number of cells in a filtered column that matches a string not working

Tags: excel, vba

After filtering a table, my code below to count the number of cells in a column that matches a string is always giving me the wrong count and I'm not sure why. The header is at the second row and the column is AE

```
Sub test()

Dim ws As Worksheet, LastRow As Long, count As Integer

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

LastRow = ws.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.count

count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("AE3:AE" & LastRow), "string")

MsgBox count

End Sub
```

Comment: how wrong is it?

Comment: `LastRow` isn't a sheet row but in the worksheet function it's taking the place of one. Check the range in which you count. BTW, why isn't `LastRow` the count you want? Is "string" not the string on which you filtered?

Comment: @TimWilliams for example, after filtering a table, there is 26 cells in a column has a value of "string", but my code to count them gives numbers that are completely off

Comment: @Variatus I wish to find the count of cells in a filtered column that has a value of "string"

Comment: That is either a count of the visible cells after a filter on two fields or it is the result of a COUNTIFS worksheet function with 2 criteria. If it's the count you are after the filter isn't required and a single line of code can do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my answer:

```
    Option Explicit

Sub JustNumbers()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long 'not use var
    Dim iCount As Integer
    Dim AE As Integer 'Just the number of the column
    Dim R As Long 'for the last row
    Dim C As Long 'for the last column
    Dim L As Long 'for the last cell (row) in the sheet = 65000~ or 1048576
    Dim i As Range 'for the Loop
    
    L = Range("A1").EntireColumn.Rows.count 'for the last cell (row) in the sheet = 65000~ or 1048576
    R = Range(Cells(L, 1), Cells(L, 1)).End(xlUp).Row 'here we find the last cell (row) of your data
    'From the very last cell of the sheet, we go Up to the last cell of you data
    
    C = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2, 1)).End(xlToRight).Column 'here we find the last cell (column) of your data
    'Go over the headers to the last column, you said the headers are in the 2nd row
    
    AE = Range("AE1").Column 'Just the number of the column AE
    'it can be declare this way
    'Dim AE As Integer: AE = Range("AE1").Column
    
    Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'ok
    
    'Set the filter, that you already said you did!
    Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(R, C)).AutoFilter 'the header is the row 2
    
    '01
    'Can be multiple selection
    'Ws.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(R, C)).AutoFilter Field:=AE, Criteria1:=Array("your_value", "your_value", "your_value", "your_value"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    
    '02
    'or can be just one value
    'Ws.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(R, C)).AutoFilter Field:=AE, Criteria1:="your_value"
    'Just one line at the time, but you said the filter is alreade set.
    
    'If there are just numbers, this will do the job!
    iCount = Range(Cells(2, AE), Cells(R, AE)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).count
    
    MsgBox iCount 'your number!
End Sub

Sub TextAndNumbers()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long 'not use var
    Dim iCount As Integer
    Dim AE As Integer 'Just the number of the column
    Dim R As Long 'for the last row
    Dim C As Long 'for the last column
    Dim L As Long 'for the last cell (row) in the sheet = 65000~ or 1048576
    Dim i As Range 'for the Loop
    
    L = Range("A1").EntireColumn.Rows.count 'for the last cell (row) in the sheet = 65000~ or 1048576
    R = Range(Cells(L, 1), Cells(L, 1)).End(xlUp).Row 'here we find the last cell (row) of your data
    'From the very last cell of the sheet, we go Up to the last cell of you data
    
    C = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2, 1)).End(xlToRight).Column 'here we find the last cell (column) of your data
    'Go over the headers to the last column, you said the headers are in the 2nd row
    
    AE = Range("AE1").Column 'Just the number of the column AE
    'it can be declare this way
    'Dim AE As Integer: AE = Range("AE1").Column
    
    Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'ok
    
    'Set the filter, that you already said you did!
    Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(R, C)).AutoFilter 'the header is the row 2
    
    '01
    'Can be multiple selection
    'Ws.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(R, C)).AutoFilter Field:=AE, Criteria1:=Array("your_value", "your_value", "your_value", "your_value"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    
    '02
    'or can be just one value
    'Ws.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(R, C)).AutoFilter Field:=AE, Criteria1:="your_value"
    'Just one line at the time, but you said the filter is alreade set.
    
    'with this loop you can go for every cell that is visile
    'no matter is number or string (text)
    
    For Each i In Range(Cells(2, AE), Cells(R, AE))
        If i.Hidden = False Then
            iCount = iCount + 1
        End If
    Next i

    MsgBox iCount 'your number!
End Sub
```

Remember to choose between one line of code and another, when the 01-02 appears, if you need to set the `AutoFilter` in that part.

**Edit:**
Split the code in two because, if the data is just numbers the first will work, but it is numbers and text or just text... Well, for that is the second `Sub`.

In your code, if you do the filter, you can filter by

```
Ws.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(R, C)).AutoFilter Field:=AE, Criteria1:="=*a*", Operator:=xlAnd
```

And create a filter with part of the value/text of each cell, then you can count every cells that contain the "string", you need, or maybe use any other option en the `Text Filters`. This way you wont need `CountIF` in your code.

I may be wrong with what I just said, but this is all as I understand what you need. If you require any improvement, you can post a comment and I will read it.

[image]